# Custom labels in enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I managed to change the labels in enumerate, but when I use a `\label` and `\ref` it keeps giving me brackets like ()REQ-2.0-C. How do I get rid of the brackets?

```
%begin requirement listing definition

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries{\arabic{enumi}}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{REQ-\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}-\Alph{enumiii}}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{REQ-\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}-\Alph{enumiii}}

\makeatletter

\let\@noitemerr\relax
\show\@currentlabel

\makeatother

%end requirement listing definition
```

Comment: Please make your example compilable (MWE). That includes the documentclass and the document environment.

Comment: Is the label empty like `()REQ-2.0-C` or is it like `(REQ-2.0-C)`?

Comment: I suggest you use the `enumitem`  package: it defines keys `label=(formatting commands)` and `ref=(own formatting commands)`.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118445/

Comment: \labelenumi is used to format \item.  \p@enumi is used to format \label (actually, \@currentlabel).

Comment: Adding your code to standard `article` class produces no brackets.  Please complete your code to a compilable example demonstrating the problem.